# Concept Learning for Multiple Classes

Tags: machine-learning

Can Concept Learning be applied for learning a concept which is classified into multiple classes ?

Also, can Concept Learning algorithms like Find-S and Candidate Elimination be applied for multi-classified concepts rather than just binary classified ?